# How to follow PoLP with a cloud run application and multiple services without tight coupling

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-iam, loose-coupling, least-privilege

Imagine the following situation:

We have a gcp cloud run backend application running. Authentication is required and the ingress is set to "Internal + Load Balancing".
Other services are accessing the application via REST. Each service has it's dedicated service account with the role "roles/run.invoker".
The application is hidden behind the load balancer so that we don't have to inject the auto generated "*.run.app" url.

My issue here is that I always have to deploy my backend application first before I can assign the invoker role. I rather would not couple my backend application and other service accounts so tightly. Is there a better way without for example granting the invoker permission for example to allAuthenticatedUsers.

Comment: Do you understand what `allAuthenticatedUsers` means? That IAM member would definitely not be part of a `Principle of Least Privilege` strategy.

Comment: @JohnHanley Do you understand that this was just an example? Of course, this is not a real solution for several reasons. Do you have any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: The `machine identity` (service account assigned to a service) is tightly coupled. One of the tenants of Least Privilege is to design, deploy and enforce the properties of the identity for each deployed service.

Comment: Your question states `My issue here is that I always have to deploy my backend application first before I can assign the invoker role.`. To which identity are you referring? The service account assigned to the service or the IAM policy bound to the backend resource?